# addClass (JS, jQuery) only on first page // Shop-Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, addclass, gambio

i'm currently working to implement a template for the Gambio GX2 shop. In the template, the mainpage should be set up differently than the following pages. I would like to add a class (called "mainpage") to the mainpage in one of the following tags:

```
<body>

<div id="wrap_box" class="wrap_shop">
```

This class should only appear on the mainpage, when I open a subpage it should be gone.

A problem with these tags is that they are generated in the central template
index.php.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What URL have mainpage and subpages?

Comment: This is the official test store of Gambio:
http://www.gambio-shop.de/shop1/index.php?language=en&=&=&XTCsid=5plot0j7oim44br8kni0fn9726

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code might help. it checks your current url, then adds the class you want if it contains the name of your mainpage. removes the class if it does not.

```
if(document.url.indexOf("/mainpagename") > -1)
    $("#wrap_box").attr("class","wrap_shop");
else
    $("#wrap_box").attr("class","");
```

Comment: Thanks, the code has given me the right kick. With a few additions he worked:
`<script type="text/javascript">
var estado=window.document.location;
if (estado=="http://....")
    document.write("<div id='wrap_box' class='wrap_shop mainpage'>");
   else
    document.write("<div id='wrap_box' class='wrap_shop'>"); 
  </script>`